# Changing <img> src with a dropdown menu with Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, syncfusion

I'm new to Vue and I'm using this dropdown menu component (https://ej2.syncfusion.com/vue/documentation/drop-down-list/data-binding/) that pulls it's list items from a json array that looks like this:

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
    <div id='container'>
        <ejs-dropdownlist id='dropdownlist' placeholder='Pick a name' :dataSource='images' :fields='fields'></ejs-dropdownlist>
    </div>
    <img v-for="image in images" :key="image.url" :src="require('@/assets/pics/' + image.url)">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                images: [
                    {
                        id: 'm1',
                        name: 'Sample Name',
                        url: "../assets/pics/samplename.png"
                    },...

                    ],
                    fields : {text:'name', value:'id'}
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

What this currently does is just list out all the images at once via the `v-for` loop, but I want to grab the id/url from the selected name in the dropdown menu and pass it to the `<img>` tag to have only the corresponding image be shown below, how would I go about doing this? Thanks!

Comment: How does the dropdown list expose its selected item?  There is no `v-model` or event listening.

Comment: I'm pretty new so I'm not sure if this is what you're asking, but it exposes the selected item with the fields property, where the name and id values are binded

Comment: The `fields` prop is a one-way binding so it won't be updated with the dropdown's selections (and probably only refers to some field/column data).  After checking the docs, I see that it supports `v-model`.  I'll post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dropdown needs a `v-model="selected"` binding to communicate the selected image to the parent:

```html
<ejs-dropdownlist v-model="selected"></ejs-dropdownlist>
```

```js
data() {
  return {
    selected: null, // Used by the dropdown
    images: [...]
  }
}
```

A `v-for` would cause the template to loop through all images so you don't want that.  Remove that and use the `selected` image for the correct src:

```html
<img v-if="selected" :src="require('@/assets/pics/' + selected.url)">
```

Another issue will be that your image objects should have only the name of the image, as the `assets` path is hardcoded into the `src` binding:

```js
{
   ...
   url: "samplename.png"
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much this worked! Althought it wouldn't render at first, I had to change the "selected.url" to just "selected" and the value in the fields property had to be changed from "id" to "url".

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it helped.  It sounds like the dropdown does not automatically expose the entire data object, but only the properties you choose.  That's a choice they made when designing that component but it could have worked differently